# Как найти в гугл таблице самое большое число в диапазоне E2-E335?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Пытаюсь понять как для ячейки **Ax** написать формулу которая найдет **номер строки** в диапазоне **E2-E335** в котором стоит число в с "**x**" местом по размеру относительно других чисел в диапазоне **E2-E335**

То есть для **A1** нужно в диапазоне **E2-E335** найти номер строки **с самым большим число.**

Для **A2** нужно найти в диапазоне **E2-E335** номер строки **с вторым** по величине числом.

....и так далее до формулы в ячейке **A335** , в ячейке **A335** формула соответственно выведет номер строки для ячейки из диапазона **E2-E335** которая имеет самое маленькое значение среди других чисел что стоят в диапазоне **E2-E335**

Comment: Есть ли в диапазоне дубли значений? Если да, как быть в этом случае? (игнорировать, считать следующим...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для диапазона без дублей значений:

```
=ПОИСКПОЗ(НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(E$2:E$335;СТРОКА());E$2:E$335;)+1
```

Если в диапазоне поиска будут повторы, формула вернет положение первого (верхнего).

Для диапазона с повторами формула сложнее и, кроме этого, становится формулой массива:

```
=ПОИСКПОЗ(НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(E$2:E$335+СТРОКА(E$2:E$335)/1000;СТРОКА());E$2:E$335+СТРОКА(E$2:E$335)/1000;)+1
```

Формула массива вводится одновременным нажатием трех клавиш - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`. При этом формула должна обрамиться фигурными скобками.

Comment: подскажите, а как быть если есть например дубли? то как считать следующим?

Comment: Вариант формулы добаил в ответ

Answer (score 0):

1. Откройте Google Таблицы и перейдите на вкладку, содержащую таблицу, в которой вы хотите найти самое большое число.
2. Выделите ячейку, в которую вы хотите вывести результат.
3. Введите следующую формулу в ячейку:

   ```
   =МАКС(E2:E335)
   ```
4. Нажмите Enter.

Функция `МАКС` вычислит и выведет наибольшее число из указанного вами диапазона `E2:E335`.

Comment: Али Гусейнов, желательно читать не только заголовок, но и описание :)

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA
я создал другую тему где подробно описал проблему, но вы направили сюда, тогда тут задам. Я хочу до конца доделать формулу, но проблема в том что она берет первый попавшийся номер строки:
`=ДВССЫЛ("ITOG!D" & (ПОИСКПОЗ(НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(ARRAYFORMULA(ЗНАЧЕН(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ITOG!E$2:E$335; "%"; ""))); СТРОКА(G8)); ARRAYFORMULA(ЗНАЧЕН(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ITOG!E$2:E$335; "%"; ""))); 0) + 1))`
Скрин: https://habrastorage.org/webt/65/ce/1a/65ce1a2bca390606476508.png

Comment: В ответе я добавил формулу. Прикрутите туда удаление процентов

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA я сделал вот так: `=ArrayFormula(НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(0&ITOG!E$2:E$335; "%"; "") / 100; СТРОКА() - 1) * 100)` и это работает до тех пор пока в диапазоне `ITOG!E$2:E$335` только положительные числа. если вот такое в диапазоне `ITOG!E$2:E$335` : 
`0,05
0,2
0,3
0,4
0,5
-0,6
0,7
0,04
0,05
1`
то получаю ошибку: `Аргумент Параметр 1 в функции DIVIDE поддерживает только значения типа "число". Тип значения "0-0,6" – текст, поэтому его нельзя привести к типу "число".`
 скрин: https://prnt.sc/Icp7c9ZApb7B

Comment: расшарил таблицу: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1luPAe03P1CftTlLEHJuRLYRCN65q06dOtPkATSUw7io/edit#gid=897047891

Comment: Сначала создаем себе проблемы, а потом героически их преодолеваем :) Если в исходном диапазоне нельзя изменить данные (отделить мух от котлет), кто мешает упростить вычисления и сначала вытянуть в отдельный столбец данные, преобразованные в число (без знака %)?

Comment: Проблема решена! Просто использовал дополнительный столбец F.

А также добавил, что если есть отрицательные значения в E столбце, то формула норм их обрабатывает , выставляя значения в правильном математическом порядке вот так (как пример): - 4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 и тд.

Готовое решение в гугл таблице , может кому-то будет полезно: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XzXWxxnKPE8C4rDzp80AH4o7nH40-lg1L1aYEZ3STfE/edit#gid=1284821245