# Как брать следующее значение, если уже ранее брали подобное?

Tags: excel, excel-формулы, google-spreadsheet, google-tabs

**Формула для гугл таблицы:**

`=ДВССЫЛ("ITOG!D" & (ПОИСКПОЗ(НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(ARRAYFORMULA(ЗНАЧЕН(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ITOG!E$2:E$335; "%"; ""))); СТРОКА(G8)); ARRAYFORMULA(ЗНАЧЕН(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ITOG!E$2:E$335; "%"; ""))); 0) + 1))`

Формула отлично работает, получая номер строки где стоит самое большое число диапазона **ITOG!E2:E335** , причём в формуле я учел чтоб она убирала символы "**%**" что стоят после чисел в **ITOG!E2:E335** .

В текущей ячейке (см скрин ниже) где стоит формула (яч **A9**) функция **СТРОКА(G8)** используется как фиксированное число для функции **НАИБОЛЬШИЙ**, чтобы получить **k**-е по величине значение из массива, где **k** равно **8**. Это означает, что формула для места где она стоит (яч **A9**) будет искать **восьмое** по величине значение в диапазоне **ITOG!E2:E335**
С этим в формуле всё окей!

Формула берет номер **первой найденной** строки в диапазоне **ITOG!E2:E335** , где находится наибольшее число, допустим это строка с номером "**x**".
Затем она возвращает соответствующее значение из ячейки **ITOG!Dx** и помещает его в ячейку **Ay** где собственно эта формула и стоит.

*Пример проблемы:*
**Но!** если у нас в диапазоне **ITOG!E2:E335** есть одинаковые значения, то формула возьмёт номер **первой найденной** строки с **8-ой** по величине цифрой из диапазона **ITOG!E2:E335**.

И т.к. в нашем примере в диапазоне **ITOG!E2:E335** **8-ое** по величине наибольшее значение  стоит в ячейках **ITOG!E2** и в **ITOG!E10** и оно одинаково , то формула выведет в **A9** и **A10** значение из ячейки **ITOG!D2**

То из двух одинаковых номеров строк - она возьмет первую найденную строку и по этому в нашем примере она возьмет строку с номером **2**.
[image]

Comment: Дубль вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1566278/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5-e2-e335